# Using a for loop to select items and put them into a list

Tags: python, sqlite

So I am querying a database that is called golfDB and it consists of one table called players with 5 fields:

- name (player's name)
- totalGross (sum of the gross scores from each round)
- totalRounds (number of rounds played)
- pars (total number of pars made)
- birdies (total number of birdies made)

In this function below I am trying to find the player/ players with the most pars.  It turns out that there are two players, so I am trying to figure out a way to make this print out better because currently it is printing the print statement twice but with the different player at the end.  I want to be able to make what I have designated as players be a list of both players, and then somehow print the players in the print statement more coherently.  Any ideas?

```
def queryDBpars(cursor):
    """find out which player had the most pars"""
    cursor.execute('select name, pars from players where pars = (select max(pars) from players)')
    playerPars= cursor.fetchall()
    for items in playerPars:
        players= (items[0])
        print('The player(s) with the most pars is/are', players)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the players in a list, and use [join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) in the print statement to show combine the list.

```
players = list()
for items in playerPars:
    players.append(items[0])
print('The player(s) with the most pars is/are', ', '.join(players))
```

If you want to make it more elegant you could use [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

```
players = [player[0] for player in playerPars]
```

It would output: `The player(s) with the most pars is/are player1, player2`

If you want to check the number of players so that you can format the text properly you could do something like this.

```
if len(players) > 1:
    print('The player(s) with the most pars are', ', '.join(players))
elif len(players) == 1:
    print('The player with the most pars is %s' % players[0])
```

Comment: A list comprehension would've been nicer.

Comment: True @ThijsvanDien. But, I intentionally wanted to keep it simple and easy to understand. If I get time I might update my answer later.

Comment: Perfectly valid reason, but still I wanted it mentioned. ;) I don't suggest to get rid of `playerPars` completely, for the sake of checking if it's empty. Just the looping seemed unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to combine the names:

```
playerPars = cursor.fetchall()
print('The player(s) with the most pars is/are',
      ', '.join(p[0] for p in playerPars))
```

This joins the names with commas between them.